# booktabs: \dotrule as \midrule

Tags: booktabs

I'd like to have a dotted rule like `\midrule`from the booktabs package.

I took code from the booktabs.sty, simplified it and have:

```
    \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\makeatletter{}
\def\dotrule{\noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi
  \@aboverulesep=\aboverulesep
  \global\@belowrulesep=\belowrulesep
  \global\@thisruleclass=\@ne
  \@BTdotted}

\def\@BTdotted{%
{\CT@arc@\hrule\@height\@thisrulewidth}%
    \futurenonspacelet\@tempa\@BTendrule}

\makeatother{}
  
\begin{document}

Text

\begin{tabular}{lr}\toprule
  Huu& Haa \\\dotrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

And now I'm stuck replacing the central `\hrule\@height\@thisrulewidth`with something that makes not a line, but dots. I've been struggling with `\leaders`, but didn't get it. Maybe somebody has an idea.

I found lots of similar questions, of course. But the trick is to have a command with parameters of the booktabs package!

Comment: It will be difficult. `\hrule` is a primitive which inserts an 'rule' in the vertical list and the computation  of the length of the rule is done by TeX very late. On the other side, leaders need a box (and are able to fill that box). But we can't construct a horizontal box of the width of the array during the construction of the array...

Comment: It's possible to do something with `\multispan` but you will have to give the total number of columns of the array as argument of your command `\midrule`. We can also compute the width of the array (with PGF/Tikz) and store it in the `aux` file in order to use it in the next run.

Comment: @F.Pantigny So why did you delete the plain-tex tag? I know that there are solutions, but as you describe your insight in the contruction of \hrule, a replacement with dots seems a real TeX issue.

Comment: `plain TeX` is a format (that is to say a set of constructions with TeX primitives which is, in some way, pre-compiled). LaTeX is another format. When you use LaTeX, you don't use plain TeX: you use TeX.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a command `\dotrule` which respects the syntax and the parameters of `booktabs` (`aboverulesep`, `belowrulesep` and `lightrulewidth`) but which is available only in the environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. The dotted line is drawn by Tikz (it's possible to change the characteristics of that dotted line with the tools of Tikz).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter

\cs_set:Npn \dotrule 
  { 
    \noalign \bgroup 
    \peek_meaning:NTF [ 
      { \__dose_dotrule: } 
      { \__dose_dotrule: [ \lightrulewidth ] } 
  }

\cs_set:Npn \__dose_dotrule: [ #1 ]
  {
    \skip_vertical:n { \aboverulesep + \belowrulesep + #1 } 
    \egroup 
    \tl_gput_right:Nx \g_nicematrix_code_after_tl 
      { \__dose_dotrule:nn { \int_use:N \c@iRow } { #1 } }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__dose_dotrule:nn 
  {
    {
      \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { \aboverulesep + ( #2 ) / 2 }
      \CT@arc@
      \tikz \draw [ dotted , line~width = #2 ]
        ([yshift=-\l_tmpa_dim]#1-|1) 
        -- 
        ([yshift=-\l_tmpa_dim]#1-| \int_eval:n { \c@jCol + 1 }) ;
    }   
  }

\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cc}
\toprule
Header 1 & Header 2 \\
\dotrule
text & text \\
some text & other text \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
%
\hspace{2cm}
%
\begin{NiceTabular}{cc}
\toprule
Header 1 & Header 2 \\
\midrule
text & text \\
some text & other text \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}


\vspace{1cm}


\arrayrulecolor{blue}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cc}
\toprule
Header 1 & Header 2 \\
\dotrule[3pt]% <-- mandatory
text & text \\
some text & other text \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
%
\hspace{2cm}
%
\begin{NiceTabular}{cc}
\toprule
Header 1 & Header 2 \\
\midrule[3pt]
text & text \\
some text & other text \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Instead of improving booktabs you basically improved nicematrix: with your patch it will recognize the booktabs commands with a new feature: dotted lines. I'm skimming through the manual of nicematrix and that package looks really great; booktabs has even been implemented yet! So I'll have to teach the commands of nicematrix to Emacs. I often use datatool and numprint, so maybe I'll come back with a question on that later. However, thank you very much for (a) the nice package and (b) this answer!

Comment: The command `\dotrule[3pt]` needs a `%` sign at the end, otherwise the next row in the tabular will begin with a space. Write: `\dotrule[1pt]%` or whatever value is inside the bracket.

Comment: You are right. I have added a `%` in the code.

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution with `booktabs` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{booktabs}{lll}
\toprule
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
\midrule[dashed]
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
\midrule[dotted]
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
\bottomrule 
\end{booktabs}

\end{document}
```

[image]